# SkiaSharp drawing with OpenGL/Vulkan backend from console application

Tags: c#, opengl, .net-core, vulkan, skiasharp

I want to draw something with GPU acceleration (using OpenGL or Vulkan) using SkiaSharp and save the image later. There is no need to display the image anywhere in the application, because it's a console application targeting Windows and Linux.

I already tried the following code, with various variations, but nothing worked (raises an exception at `var surface = SKSurface.Create(context, false, info);` because `glInterface` and `context` are `null`.

Can somebody give me a hint?

```cs
var glInterface = GRGlInterface.Create();
var context = GRContext.CreateGl(glInterface);

var info = new SKImageInfo(256, 256);
var surface = SKSurface.Create(context, false, info);
var canvas = surface.Canvas;
```

In the end it would be nice to have the ability to call `SKBitmap.SetPixels(IntPrt)` or something similar to set the resulting bitmap buffer to a specific place.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is you need to manually create an OpenGL context first.
Have a look at https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/blob/master/tests/Tests/GRContextTest.cs for implementation details.

For copying the rendered pixel buffer you can use `SKSurface.ReadPixels`.

Comment: Another way is to use a library like OpenTK to do all the work for you without you having to use your own interop. I just don't use it in the tests because that was what I did at the time. For actual apps, you probably want to look at using an OpenGL/Vulkan library to make sure all things are working. And, then you probably could re-use code as well.

Comment: I tried to use OpenTK in the first place, but was unable to create a context with a window